# Can these ordinal variables be aggregated?

Tags: nonparametric, mean, ordinal-data, aggregation

I have an ordinal dependent measure that has been taken over 12 time points at the same 180 locations on each occasion. It consists of a 4-point ant density rating that relates to specific numbers of ants (0 = zero ants; 1 = 1 to 10 ants; 2 = 11-49 ants; 3 = 50+ ants).

I would like to aggregate some of the time points so that there are fewer of them. I know it is usually unacceptable to aggregate ordinal data but as the ratings relate to specific numbers of ants would it be possible in this case?

For example, the first two time points do not differ significantly so could they be collapsed together by calculating the mean ratings of the two and then the same done to time points 3, 4, and 5? This would create 2 new aggregated time points that could be compared for significant differences using a non-parametric test.

Comment: I think if you do what I think you want to do you would have to do it across all time points. Is this what you are thinking t{1, 2, 3, 4} v{2, 2, 4, 4}. to using the mean to aggregate across two time intervals, t:{1-2, 3-4} v:{2, 4}.